# Referencing through double nested fields returns wrong result

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Groups which own Categories which own Exams.

When I run this code, instead of calling the Exams within the respective Group loop, it scatters the Exams across Groups that don't own them.

```
<%  @header_groups.order("slug ASC").each do |group| %>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown-3" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <%= group.name %><span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown-3">
      <%  @header_exams.where(group: group.id).each do |exam| %>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/<%= exam.group.slug %>/<%= exam.slug %>/">
            <%= exam.name %>
          </a>
          <!--TODO: use <a class="active"> to denote the current page and possibly category-->
        <% end %>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="/<%= group.slug %>/">
        All <%= group.name %>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Within my controllers I've defined

```
@header_groups = Group.where(published: TRUE)
@header_exams = Exam.where(published: TRUE)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong in my reference structure?

EDIT: Model relationships added below.

Group model

```
    has_many :categories, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :exams, through: :categories, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories
```

Category model

```
    belongs_to :group
    has_many :exams, :dependent => :destroy
```

Exam model

```
    belongs_to :category
    has_one :group, through: :category
```

Comment: can you show your model relationships

Comment: done - I've added the models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based from your data relationship above I think you simplyfy, below is sample code for your problem above

in your controller you can joins conditions, this also eager load your query so your database just called only once

below is sample for your controller

```
@header_groups = Group.joins(categories: :exams).
                 where("groups.published = ? AND exams = ?",true,true).
                 order("slug")
```

and your view will view based only @header_groups, to get exams you can use @header_examps = group.exams (remember you also mentioned in your model relationship that group has_many exams through category)

```
<%  @header_groups.each do |group| %>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown-3" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <%= group.name %><span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown-3">
      <% @header_examps = group.exams %>
      <%  @header_exams.each do |exam| %>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/<%= exam.group.slug %>/<%= exam.slug %>/">
            <%= exam.name %>
          </a>
          <!--TODO: use <a class="active"> to denote the current page and possibly category-->
        <% end %>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="/<%= group.slug %>/">
        All <%= group.name %>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

**Update from original poster with the final working code:**

What ended up working for me was a slight variant of this answer. (The answer as written above repeated the entire group loop for every exam, rather than just for each group.)

Controller:

```
    @header_groups_v3 = Group.where(published: TRUE).
         order("slug")
```

View:

```
    <%  @header_groups_v3.each do |group| %>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown-3" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <%= group.name %><span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown-3">
          <% @header_examps = group.exams %>
          <%  @header_examps.each do |exam| %>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/<%= exam.group.slug %>/<%= exam.slug %>/">
              <%= exam.name %>
            </a>
              <!--TODO: use <a class="active"> to denote the current page and possibly category-->
          <% end %>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="/<%= group.slug %>/">
            All <%= group.name %>
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: thanks much - I've proposed an edit with the code that worked, but your example above got me 90% there. basically I just needed to make a couple small changes to avoid repeating the entire group loop for every exam.

Answer (score 0):

With some code substitution and omitting the irrelevant bits, what I'm reading is:

```rb
Group.where(published: TRUE).each do |group|
  Exam.where(published: TRUE, group: group.id).each do |exam|
  end
end
```

Which is a little confusing because `Exam` does not have a `:group` column, but there's a `Exam.where(group:)` ActiveRecord query.

Instead of diving into ActiveRecord -> SQL queries, can you try doing something like this first:

```rb
Group.where(published: true).includes(:exams).each do |group|
  group.exams.each do |exam|
  end
end
```